# If column and row value are empty or whitespace srping, full with value from a different particular column

Tags: python, pandas

If rows of a column are empty or whitespace strings, I want to fill them with the corresponding row values of a particular column.

Here is a minimal example,

Starting dataframe

```
d1 = [['a', 'b', '3', 'd', '8', '9'], ['q', '', 'j', ' ', 'g', '\n']]

dtest = pd.DataFrame(d1).transpose()
dtest


0   1
0   a   q
1   b   
2   3   j
3   d   
4   8   g
5   9   \n
```

And I am stuck trying to figure out how to create a dataframe which would result in the following.

```
result = [['a', 'b', '3', 'd', '8', '9'], ['q', 'b', 'j', 'd', 'g', '9']]

resultdf = pd.DataFrame(result).transpose()
resultdf


0   1
0   a   q
1   b   b
2   3   j
3   d   d
4   8   g
5   9   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `strip` and `where`:

```
dtest[1] = dtest[1].where(dtest[1].str.strip().ne(''), dtest[0])
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  a  q
1  b  b
2  3  j
3  d  d
4  8  g
5  9  9
```